# simple javascript file keeps returning 301 with cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using cloudfront for a simple javascript asset that is the following:

```
https://d1syjrf5lltxmn.cloudfront.net/Content/JavaScript/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js
```

I've got the Origin Domain name and path set to

```
www.siliconvalley-codecamp.com
```

Origin type is custom origin, policy i sMatch Viewer, view policy is http and https.  Problem is when it hit this (over and over) it keeps returning a 301 and doing another request from my origin server.

I can't figure out why it keeps doing the 301's. I've read others having issues but can not find a solution.

```
GET https://d1syjrf5lltxmn.cloudfront.net/Content/JavaScript/jquery-migrate-    1.2.1.min.js HTTP/1.1
Host: d1syjrf5lltxmn.cloudfront.net
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.99 Safari/537.36
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

and the return is:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 208
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://www.siliconvalley-codecamp.com/Content/JavaScript/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 23 Jan 2015 04:18:21 GMT
Age: 10575
X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 f86dab587205f74a0e6f36b42207dec2.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: 8h4R0WTOl1wg8LDafMoeAkcvOr1G8ujfAVMgz84Uy_BVE8QlxTbTrQ==

<head><title>Document Moved</title></head>
<body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found <a     HREF="https://www.siliconvalley-codecamp.com/Content/JavaScript/jquery-migrate- 1.2.1.min.js">here</a></body>
```

Origin server setup:

[image]

Comment: It appears your origin server is at fault- not Cloudfront.

Comment: @tedder42 where do you see that?

Comment: Also, it appears images are not getting 301, just js files.

Comment: I see that because the server headers in the response indicate IIS/ASP.

Comment: @tedder42 is undoubtedly correct in this assertion.  The redirect absolutely came from your origin server.  .. however, note the `Age:` of the cached object.  If you fixed the origin server since Cloudfront cached it, you're not going to see a behavior change until you invalidate the cached object in Cloudfront.  What do you see in the origin server's logs from the time the request was processed?

Comment: does disabling and reneabling the cache clear it all?  I don't see where the logs are.

Comment: also, I added my origin server current setup to question